# Update target view position when dependent view is hidden in coordinatorLayout

Tags: android-coordinatorlayout

I have a view A which has a dependency with another view B. When I am trying to hide this view B, the view A's position is still the same. The ideal would be if view B's visibility is GONE, the view A should update its position.

In view behavior, there is a method called onDependentViewChanged(), but based on the comments of this method, the view A's position will only be changed when view B's position is changed. But i do not want to change view B position, just hide it.

So if i want to updated view A's position when view B is hidden, how would i do that.

Thanks

====

I also tried with updating the view inside onDependentViewRemoved, but not sure why this method not get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, after checking the source code of CoordinatorLayout, found one interface method onLayoutChild() is what i want. Just implement this method in custom behavior file and inside this method, update target view's position based on dependent view's visibility.